# JSON.stringify returns empty object when parsing complex object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I know this question has been asked quite a lot before, but I spent more than 4 hours trying to figure out what is the problem but I didn't have any luck to find a similar case. I have complex javascript object that I need to convert it to Json using Json.stringfy() method, but the problem is I'm always getting empty Object. [Here is a screenshot for the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTp7s.jpg), 
and [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvhA.jpg) I'm getting after calling json.stringfy().

Here is the code for creation the object:

```
function Step2() {
    debugger;
    //Get all table rows
    var tableRows = $('#ProjectsTable > tbody  > tr');

    //Remove first two rows
    tableRows.splice(0, 2);
    var tds = []
    tableRows.each(function () {

        tds.push($(this).find('td'));

    })
    var self = new Object();
    self.Projects = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

        self.Projects.push([]);
        self.Projects[i].Years = new Array();
        self.Projects[i].ProjectName = "";


        self.Projects[i].ProjectName = $(tds[i][0]).find('span').text();
        for (var j = 1; j < tds[i].length;) {

            var Year = new Object();
            Year.TimeAllocated = $(tds[i][j++]).text();
            Year.Duration = $(tds[i][j++]).text();
            Year.Cost = $(tds[i][j++]).text();
            self.Projects[i].Years.push(Year);

        }
    }
    return self;
}


function SubmitStep2() {
    debugger;
    var request =  Step2();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(request);
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ResearchGrant/ProjectManpower",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonData ,
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        ShowSuccessMessage();
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status + xhr.error);
    })
}
```

Comment: But...your not calling json.stringfy() anywhere in the code above?! If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) people may be able to help, right now you're just asking us to guess

Comment: Also, please stop using screenshots. 90% of the time they're totally unhelpful. Post code and details of recreation steps, screenshots just show results, not how you got there

Comment: I feel like your are using stringify before the projects are added to your object. Is your code asynchrone?

Comment: @Liam I tried to add screenshots using Imgur embedded in stackoverflow but It won't work sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
    self.Projects.push([]);
    self.Projects[i].Years = new Array();
```

In this case, `self.projects[i]` is an array, which means it doesn't (can't) have an attribute called `Years`. Instead, push a new Object:

```
    self.Projects.push({});
    self.Projects[i].Years = new Array();
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response and your very simple and self contained answer. World with people like you is much nicer place, thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I have initialised as array but treated that as object.

That resulted in empty object after JSON.stringify.

```
let sample: any = [];
Object.assign(sample, {item : "a"});
let stringfied = JSON.stringify(sample);
```

Worked out after correcting the type.

```
let sample: any = {};
```